# JS anonymous function and parentNode to delete a table row

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have an HTML table that has a delete button in the last column of every row. I am attempting to make each complete row deletable using the JS code below. I am able to get a console readout of what seems to be the correct `tr` to delete with console.log but am unable to figure out the code for actually deleting it:

```
var bns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for (var i = 0; i < bns.length; i++) {
    bns[i].addEventListener("click", function()
     {
      console.log(this.parentNode.parentNode);
     });
 }
```

Comment: show your html file and what you have tried so far, for get the answer to your question

Comment: To delete any node, use `node.parentNode.removeChild(node)`. I'm sure there are many duplicates here, but it's easier to just answer in a comment…